# Type of key attribute in array is not sufficiently strict

Tags: typescript

I believe I've managed to use generics so that the `DataPresentation` component's `searchKey` prop can only be one of the values of `field` in `columns`

```
type Props<RowType extends AnyObject, ColType extends string> = {
  columns: ReadonlyArray<{ readonly field: ColType }>;
  rows: RowType[];
  searchKey?: ColType;
};

const DataPresentation = <RowType extends AnyObject, ColType extends string>({
  columns, rows, searchKey,
}: Props<RowType, ColType>) => { ... }
```

Here I am using the component:

```
export const playerPropsColumns = [
  { field: 'sportId' }, // todo: get sport name. from backend?
  { field: 'playerName' },
  { field: 'line' },
  { field: 'status' },
] as const;


// inside a component
<DataPresentation
  columns={playerPropsColumns}
  rows={data}
  searchKey={'XXXXX'}
/>
```

That invalid searchKey passes the type check, but it's more interesting than simply "it's not working." When I hover over `searchKey`, its type is:

```
searchKey?: "line" | "sportId" | "playerName" | "status" | "XXXXX" | undefined
```

and `playerPropsColumns`'s type is

```
columns: readonly {readonly field: "line" | "sportId" | "playerName" | "status" | "XXXXX"}[]
```

So it's getting the acceptable values from the `playerPropsColumns` array, but it's also accepting whatever I feed into `searchKey` which obviously completely defeats the point of type checking.

What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Note: I will say that all the read-only stuff is so I could use `as const` in my definition of the columns, so that I could do `type FieldType = typeof playerPropsColumns[number]['field'];`. However, after setting all this up and using generics I realize I of course didn't need that typedef at all, so maybe I can get rid of the read only stuff, and maybe they're the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are observing here is intended behaviour. The `readonly` modifiers are not the problem here. When you use a generic type for multiple parameters, the types of those parameters will join together in a union.

```
function test<T extends string>(a: T, b: T) {}

test("a", "b")
// function test<"a" | "b">(a: "a" | "b", b: "a" | "b"): void
```

---

So how can you solve this problem?

Instead of using `T` to store a union of possible values, you could use `T` to store the whole tuple.

```
type Props<ColTypes extends readonly { field: string }[]> = {
  columns: ColTypes;
  searchKey?: ColTypes[number];
};

const DataPresentation = <
  ColTypes extends readonly { field: string }[]
>({
  columns, searchKey,
}: Props<ColTypes>) => {}
```

We can now use `ColTypes[number]["field"]` to constain the type of the field `searchKey`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=15&pln=5&pc=40#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGcAeAYQgBsAVapJuEgAeMJADsAJgKIoJEMZ0pwA3nEzAknCQC44TGFGBiA5nAC%20AbQC6APjgBeFaThw0XAK4gxTXRx58mAG5nPVQoNAALAGkkSgB%20Xy5eGiYLMU8AIyQoKwt8dU0JfCtgs2DSN294ABEUGBQGfnF6mGB5BzgWEL9k-kERcSk4GTkFJVUCrV19QxNza1IbAAplELdOT28AGlCUcOjYrdIzXQYIZnYkgJsASgc7ZTNyYUhYV3l9ODBOFEpss%20Yfk2AkcFhCEw0UzgAHImK8YABJCTQ8w7AD0aLgMAgcl0xiQ8Dh0HgYhQICQADo1Dg8Bl0ABrQZxcFqSE6GHfX7ZAByZKQKLMRxcEMKumhnCM-NRLMm7NhLXcTAFRyscBQAkq%20nKtXqjSYzTqbTEK3WwN0nL%20UABTCBXiYO31e0iMUounwAA1PfgzDdyEA)

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Less generics are better than more, typically.

Comment: Although the rules for when it merges and when constrains seems little more nuanced: https://tsplay.dev/NDyDVm

Comment: @AlexWayne interesting. I wonder what the logic is here

Comment: Should I be getting rid of any of the `readonly` or `as const`?

Comment: if you get rid of `readonly`, you will lose the ability the pass any premade arrays (created with `as const` to the function. Since non-`readonly` arrays can still be passed as to the function even if arguments are marked as `readonly`, I would say it's good to keep the `readonly`.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasS. Only thing is, the types of the columns are to be given as a prop to a MUI `DataGrid`, which has a `GridColumns` type (which includes `{ field: string}`. I'd love to be able to enforce the type of the columns using this type but it's not letting me assign the `as const` to that mutable type. Can I only have one or the other? Typing the columns as `GridColumns` OR typing the searchKey as previously described?

Answer (score 2):

You can make `SearchKey` a separate generic parameter which extends `ColType` so Typescript knows which is to be inferred as an input type, and which is a constraint.

For example:

*(Note I removed `rows` since it has nothing to do with the actual issue here)*

```
type Props<
  ColType extends string,
  SearchKey extends ColType
> = {
  columns: ReadonlyArray<{ readonly field: ColType }>;
  searchKey?: SearchKey;
};

const DataPresentation = <
  ColType extends string,
  SearchKey extends ColType
>({
  columns,
  searchKey,
}: Props<ColType, SearchKey>) => {
  return <></>
}
```

Now the example works as you would expect:

```
export const playerPropsColumns = [
  { field: 'sportId' }, 
  { field: 'playerName' },
  { field: 'line' },
  { field: 'status' },
] as const;

const testA = <DataPresentation
  columns={playerPropsColumns}
  searchKey='line'
/> // fine

const testB = <DataPresentation
  columns={playerPropsColumns}
  searchKey='XXXXX' 
/> // error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=3&pln=21&pc=1#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)