# Type-constrained "find" call is still possibly undefined

Tags: typescript

As a followup to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72664665/6826164), I have the following function:

```
export const getUniqueValuesForFilters = <
  RowType extends AnyObject,
  Columns extends readonly { field: string }[],
>(
  rows: RowType[],
  columnConfig: readonly {
    field: Columns[number]['field'];
    valueGetter?: ({ row }: { row: RowType }) => string;
  }[],
  ...filters: readonly { field: Columns[number]['field'] }[][]
): Record<Columns[number]['field'], FilterOption[]> => {
  const fields = filters.map(list => list?.map(f => f.field)).flat(); 
  const uniqueValuesTable = fields.reduce((obj, field) => {
    const allValuesForField = rows.map(row => {
      const column = columnConfig.find(c => c.field === field)
      // we only need a valueGetter if we're not directly getting the value from that property of the row.
      if (!column.valueGetter) return row[field as keyof RowType];
      return column.valueGetter({ row });
    });
    const uniqueValuesForField = [...new Set(allValuesForField)];
    const valuesAsOptions = uniqueValuesForField.map(value => ({
      value,
      label: value,
    }));

    return {
      ...obj,
      [field]: valuesAsOptions,
    };
  }, {});

  return uniqueValuesTable as Record<Columns[number]['field'], FilterOption[]>;
};
```

The issue I'm having is that typescript is saying that `column` is possibly undefined. I understand that `Array.prototype.find` could possibly fail, which would indeed leave `column` undefined.

However, `columnConfig` and `filters` are properly typed such that all the filters' `field` properties should be valid fields of the `columnConfig` and therefore I would imagine that typescript would know that `find` should always succeed.

Casting `column` with `as typeof columnConfig[number];` silences the error (as does a non-null assertion), but I don't think I should need that.

Hovering over both `c.field` and `field` in the callback of `columnConfig.find` shows that they are both of the same type, `Columns[number]["field"]`. I do also see that `uniqueValuesTable` is being inferred as `(string | RowType[keyof RowType])[]` -- which seems fine to me but I thought mentioning because my brain is pretty bursting here and maybe I'm missing something.

For what it's worth, the following test passes **and** has no TS errors.

```
describe('getUniqueValuesForFilters', () => {
  it('works, god dammit', () => {
    const columnConfig = [
      { field: 'name' },
      {
        field: 'uppercaseName',
        valueGetter: ({ row: { name } }: { row: { name: string } }) => name.toUpperCase(),
      },
    ] as const;
    
    const rows = [{ name: 'alice' }, { name: 'bob' }, { name: 'Bob' }];
    
    const filters: Array<Array<{ field: typeof columnConfig[number]['field'] }>> = [
      [{ field: 'name' }],
      [{ field: 'uppercaseName' }],
    ];
    
    const result = getUniqueValuesForFilters(rows, columnConfig, ...filters);
    
    expect(result['name'].map(o => o.value)).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(['alice', 'bob', 'Bob']));
    expect(result['uppercaseName'].map(o => o.value)).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(['ALICE', 'BOB']));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and therefore I would imagine that typescript would know that find should always succeed.

No, TypeScript will not go that far - that's just not the sort of inference TypeScript can make. `.find` is explicitly typed to include `undefined` as a possibility, *no matter what*.

```
find<S extends T>(
    predicate: (this: void, value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => value is S,
    thisArg?: any
): S | undefined;

find(
    predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => unknown, 
    thisArg?: any
): T | undefined;
```

The only type-related information passed to `.find` (and thereby the only thing TypeScript can infer as a result from that) is

- the type of an array item, and
- (optionally) a generic argument that asserts that, if a value is found, the value is of a certain type

But there's nothing that will go through the logic of your program and identify that something absolutely will be found by `.find`.

If you're absolutely sure it'll always find a match, just assert that the result isn't `undefined`.

```
const column = columnConfig.find(c => c.field === field)!;
```

Comment: I'm surprised there's such a valid case for force-unwrapping. But that all makes sense, thanks!